# Invoke the copy construction of a derived class from a pointer to the base class?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, copy-constructor, dynamic-allocation

I have

```
1- class A {int m;};
2- class B: public A
{float n;};
3- class C: public A
{string n;};
```

I store all instances of class A in

```
vector <class A*> myInstansesofA;
```

It is stored as a pointer because I dynamically create them according to some if statement

```
if (some condition)
{
      A* newA = new B();
      myInstancesofA.push_back(newA );
}
else
{
      A* newA = new C();
      myInstancesofA.push_back(newA );
}
```

Now I need to create an exact copy of the vector. With new set of pointers, but exact copy of the data.

Problem is in copying the data for each instance of A (which are actually B and C) to the new vector.

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
for (vector<A*>::const_iterator it = myInstancesofA.begin(); it != myInstancesofA.end(); ++it)
    {
        A* newA = new A(*(*it));
        myInstancesofA.push_back(newA );
    }
```

I suspect this error occurs because of "new A" invokes only the copy constructor for type A and does not invoke of B or C (I dubugged and found this was happening).

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you cannot invoke the constructor like that, and there is no straight-forward way in C++ to do something similar (it is pretty straight-forward for language with Reflection, like Java and C#).

One way is to make use of [prototype pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern)

```
class A {
public:
    virtual A* clone() {
        return new A {...};
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    A* clone() override {
        return new B {.........};
    }
};

class C : public A {
public:
    A* clone() override {
        return new C {.........};
    }
};
```

The object itself is responsible to create a clone of itself.  Of course more thing to improve on the design but at least it gives you a taste of it.

Comment: Good lead, but a few minor details: `B` and `C` should be derived from `A`, and `new B()` is slower than `new B` (it's required to perform zero initialisation before default construction) - no reason to use it here; ideally the OP would add constructors to set whatever fields were necessary and simplify to e.g. `return new B(...args...);`. Finally, it's a good practice to use `override` rather than `virtual` for `B::clone` and `C::clone`.

Comment: @TonyD Gosh I can't imagine I missed those obvious stuff, fixing them (I think I need some coffee) :P  for `new B()` I am not aware of the difference you mentioned, can lead me to some info on it? (sorry off topic I know :P )

Comment: I need a coffee too!  Anyway, in the C++11 Standard 4.3.4/17 requires "If the new-initializer is omitted, the object is default-initialized (8.5); if no initialization is performed, the object has indeterminate value. — Otherwise, the new-initializer is interpreted according to the initialization rules of 8.5 for directinitialization.", under 8.5/11 and /17 `()` without arguments implies "value initialized", which is described in 8.5/8, which specifies zero initialisation first if there's a compiler-provided default constructor.